# DHCP moved from

Tags: ubuntu, dhcp, pfsense, raspberry

After connecting several Raspberry Pis running Ubuntu 23.10 to my switch, they are for some reason stepping on each others DHCP leases. DHCP is running on fpsense 2.7.2... Logs:

```
DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.2.2 from d8:3a:dd:75:3c:2c (pi-storage-4) via re0
DHCPACK on 192.168.2.2 to d8:3a:dd:75:3c:2c (pi-storage-4) via re0.   <--- happy
...
DHCPDISCOVER from d8:3a:dd:74:ed:e6 (pi-storage-4) via re0    <-- pi-storage-5 starts, DHCP thinks it pi-storage-4 for some reason.
DHCPOFFER on 192.168.2.2 to d8:3a:dd:74:ed:e6 (pi-storage-5) via re0   <-- DHCP gives away the lease...
DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.2.2 (192.168.0.1) from d8:3a:dd:74:ed:e6 (pi-storage-5) via re0
DHCPACK on 192.168.2.2 to d8:3a:dd:74:ed:e6 (pi-storage-5) via re0

arp: 192.168.2.2 moved from d8:3a:dd:75:3c:2c to d8:3a:dd:74:ed:e6 on re0  <-- arp table sees the change....
```

The problem I see is `pi-storage-4` already has `192.168.2.2` and when `pi-storage-5` comes online, it asks for the same address, and pfsense DHCP server just grants it, then makes the arp change. This is problematic. I can't tell yet if this is Ubuntu asking for someone else's lease, or the DHCP server thinking `pi-storage-5` is `pi-storage-4` for some reason... Has anyone seen this?

Comment: Did you clone these systems from a common image, so that they may have the same cache?

Comment: Used the raspberry pi imager and entered the host names for each image. That has worked many times before for me.

Comment: Was the ancestor image booted on your network? If so delete `/var/lib/dhcp/*`.

Comment: So I see that dir is empty at first boot, the host has grabbed someone else's lease already though. So I run:
`sudo dhclient -r && sudo dhclient`

and now I see:
```
cat /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.leases 
lease {
  interface "eth0";
  fixed-address 192.168.2.60;
  option subnet-mask 255.255.252.0;
...
```

Comment: but also see:
```
$ ip addr show dev eth0
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d8:3a:dd:75:4b:f2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.2.2/22 metric 100 brd 192.168.3.255 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 3635sec preferred_lft 3635sec
    inet 192.168.2.60/22 brd 192.168.3.255 scope global secondary dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 7015sec preferred_lft 7015sec
    inet6 fe80::da3a:ddff:fe75:4bf2/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Seems it doesn't want to give up that stollen address...

Comment: Okay, so there is also a lease in 
```
$ cat /run/systemd/netif/leases/2
# This is private data. Do not parse.
ADDRESS=192.168.2.2
NETMASK=255.255.252.0
ROUTER=192.168.0.1
SERVER_ADDRESS=192.168.0.
....
```

Comment: Okay, sikmalier issue here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030957/second-ip-via-dhcp-why

I'n my case, I want to get rid of primary., so I deleted `/run/systemd/netif/leases/2` and restarted, that worked, but what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this must be an issue with `Raspberry Pi Imager v1.8.3` when installing Ubuntu. It seems Ubuntu uses a [machine_id](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/machine-id.html) when requesting a DHCP lease and since all the images I made had the same `/etc/machine_id` the DHCP server would hand out the ip address to what ever number of Pis were on the network with this image. I had not seen this behavior before with Ubuntu and Raspberry Pis. So, in order to get these Pis to get their own lease after first boot...

```
$ sudo rm /etc/machine-id && sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dbus/machine-id
$ sudo systemd-machine-id-setup
$ sudo reboot
```

This will regenerate a new random machine_id and the DHCP server will hand out a new lease.

Open questions:

1. How does Ubuntu pass this machine_id to the DHCP server? Thought it used mac, not seeing it in tcpdump of DHCP.
2. Why did this just start? Is it a change in how Ubuntu ask for the lease or a change in how `Raspberry Pi Imager` creates the image?

Comment: Question 1: DHCP uses an [identifier](https://techhub.hpe.com/eginfolib/networking/docs/switches/5130ei/5200-3942_l3-ip-svcs_cg/content/483572383.htm) that apparently you can set to almost whatever you want. In Ubuntu it is hashing the machine_id and passing that, but you can change the config to use the mac address. https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/82229